# What's the right Java generic for a collection of elements with unique addressable indices?

Tags: java, database, collections

I'm on my way to programming a database application and in our course we are told to implement a library of elements using one of the Java Collections. Each of the elements has a unique ID with which it's supposed to be addressed. Now I am wondering how this can be done.

I though about using a ListArray but this won't work because the only way of addressing List elements is through the index which you can't control.

Do you have some advice for me?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Use a [`HashMap<Integer, MyObject>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): `map.put(object.getId(), object);`

Comment: Also, you could consider using something out of the Guava library.  It has some extra collection classes not available in the regular JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have said, you want to use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), of which [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is an implementation.

```
Map<String, String> library = new HashMap<String, String>();

library.put("key", "value");

String value = library.get("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map<IndexType, YourEntityType>`. `Map` is an interface; the most commonly used implementation is `HashMap`.